# Understanding Weak Entities and Weak Relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database, erd

If I have the following ERD:

```
 ------
|Inv   |
---------
   1

   |
 <<contains>>

   |
   m
--------
--------                             ---------
||Line  ||  1 --- <<has a>> --- 1  | prod     |
--------                            ----------
--------
```

Where `Line` is a weak entity, and `contains` and `has a` are weak relationships, what would the primary key for Line look like?

I've been looking online and I'd like to think it would be a composite primary key consisting of:

```
PK = (ID from line, Primary Key from Inv, Primary Key from Prod)
```

Can anyone help me out? Am I right? Where'd I go wrong? etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been looking online and I'd like to think it would be a composite primary key consisting of:

```
PK = (ID from line, Primary Key from Inv, Primary Key from Prod)
```

No, the primary key from Inv and the line item number are sufficient to identify a row in the table "Line". If you want to implement a further business requirement--that each product can appear only once per invoice--you can make an additional unique constraint on the pair of columns {value from Inv, value from Prod}.

As a practical matter, I wouldn't use autoincrementing id numbers in "Inv" *or* in "Line". Autoincrementing id numbers can leave gaps, and accountants hate gaps. By extension, database people hate gaps in these kinds of numbers, too. (We're the ones who get blamed for "missing" rows.)

You need to be careful about storing the id number for a product, too. If the product name changes, it will appear to change on all past invoices. That's a good way to get on the bad side of a judge in court.